# Slide parent DIV to top when input field is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When someone clicks on a specific input field on my website, particularly on a mobile device, I need the parent div of the input field to slide to the top of the page. I need this because the keyboard that pops up covers the entire div below the input field, which is showing the user the items that they are filtering through. I've laid out the problem below graphically. I'd appreciate some guidance here :)

Starting state:

[image]

Finished state:

[image]

Comment: You can try to trigger it with `click()` and then smoothly animate the position of your parent element with `animate()`.
Could you also post a fiddle with a basic setup? Would be easier to write you a proper answer.

Comment: Show the code what you've tried so far?

Comment: The answer depends on the how the page is marked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this oughtta do:

```
$('input').focus(function (event) {

  var offset = $('header').height();

  $('body, html').animate({
    scrollTop : offset
  })

})
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/busorucedo/1/edit?js,output)